# Node.js PlaceOrder on Binance issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance, binance-api-client

I am having issue placing order on Biannce using API.
I can get balance with this signature - works fine.

Placing order giving me:
{ code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' }

Have no idea what is wrong - any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const API_KEY = 'xx';
const API_SECRET = 'xx';
const BASE_URL = 'https://fapi.binance.com';

const signature = (data) => {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', API_SECRET).update(data).digest('hex');
};

const createRequestConfig = (method, endpoint, data = {}) => {
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    data.timestamp = timestamp;

    const signatureData = Object.keys(data)
        .sort()
        .map(key => `${key}=${data[key]}`)
        .join('&');

    const signatureString = `${signatureData}&timestamp=${timestamp}`;

    const config = {
        method: method,
        url: `${BASE_URL}${endpoint}?${signatureString}&signature=${signature(signatureString)}`,
        headers: {
            'X-MBX-APIKEY': API_KEY
        }
    };

    if (method === 'POST') {
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        config.data = signatureData + `&timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature(signatureString)}`;
    }

    return config;
};

const placeMarketOrder = async (symbol, side, notionalValue) => {
    const endpoint = '/fapi/v1/order';
    const data = {
        symbol: symbol,
        side: side,
        type: 'MARKET',
        quantity: 0, // Placeholder, will be calculated later
        newOrderRespType: 'FULL', // Return detailed order response
        timestamp: Date.now()
    };

    const config = createRequestConfig('POST', endpoint, data);

    try {
        const response = await axios(config);

        // Calculate quantity based on provided notionalValue and executed quantity
        const executedQty = response.data.executedQty;
        const calculatedQuantity = executedQty / notionalValue;

        console.log('Order response:', response.data);
        console.log('Calculated quantity:', calculatedQuantity);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error placing order:', error.response.data);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending with application/json content type?

```
'content-type': 'application/json',
Accept: 'application/json',
```

And now to the point of potential failure - I have no idea what you end up sending as symbol - but a safer way is to **URI encode the string** when sending.
Try this method for making the queryString (it is written in TS, so you may have to remove that if your stack doesn't support it):

```
export const makeQueryString = (q: any, noEncode: boolean = false) => {
  return Object.keys(q)
    .sort()
    .reduce((a, k) => {
      if (Array.isArray(q[k])) {
        q[k].forEach((v) => {
          a.push(k + '=' + (noEncode ? v : encodeURIComponent(v)));
        });
      } else if (q[k] !== undefined) {
        a.push(k + '=' + (noEncode ? q[k] : encodeURIComponent(q[k])));
      }
      return a;
    }, [])
    .join('&');
};
```

Another potential point of failure I heard tell of is that the timestamp must come at the very end of the querystring (and of course the signature must be built accordingly). I see that you are doing that already :)